# Get index of first non standard english character

Tags: c#, linq, character-encoding, globalization, diacritics

I'm trying to process a string and separate it into two parts when i find a character that is not of the standard english alphabet. For example `This is a stríng with áccents.` and i need to know the index of the first or every character with accent (`í`).

I think the solution is somewhere between `System.Text.Encoding` and `System.Globalization` but i miss something...

The important thing is to know if it's a character with accent and if possible exclude space.

```
void Main()
{
    var str = "This is a stríng with áccents.";
    var strBeforeFirstAccent = str.Substring(0, getIndexOfFirstCharWithAccent(str));
    Console.WriteLine(strBeforeFirstAccent);

}

int getIndexOfFirstCharWithAccent(string str){
    //Process logic
    return 13;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried accomplishing so far? I don't think `return 13` shows any attempt, at all.

Comment: Sorry i don't know how to do it. I was hoping for someone who have done it.

Comment: @GrantWinney That's a very naïve way of looking at it. ASCII is a **very limited** character set, and C#/.NET doesn't even *use ASCII* by default. C#/.NET use Unicode in UTF-16 format, which has far more `non-standard English` characters than the ASCII range of 128-165. (How about, for example, an `e` with a diacritical accent over it, which is a completely different representation than ASCII `é` or ASCII 130, which doesn't even work for my PC.)

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, From a TDD perspective, `return 13` is the perfect code for just that one string. It only becomes necessary to make the code more complex when a second string is introduced.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, sorry I was being tongue in cheek there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex `[^a-zA-Z ]` will find characters other than non-accented Roman letters and spaces.

So:

```
var regex = new Regex("[^a-zA-Z ]");
var match = regex.Match("This is a stríng with áccents.");
```

will return `í`

and `match.Index` will contain its location.

Comment: Though I'm not a fan of Regular Expressions, this is a good place for them. Also, note: this only returns the **first** instance ever. If you need others then you'll have to capture them. (That said, this answer still meets the exact criteria of the question, +1 for that.) You may also want to consider adding `0-9` to that negation block, and various other symbols.

Comment: @EBrown, I agree. Regex's have their place, but they get over-used all too often. My concern here with my own answer is that eg `,` in the string would break it. It's an answer, but I'm watching for someone else to post a better answer ;)

Comment: I just finished my non-Regex solution, I think both of them have great merit. (Your Regex solution is fewer lines of code, my non-Regex solution will not improperly tag symbols.)

Comment: `var regex = new Regex("[^\u0000-\u007F]"); var matches=regex.Matches("This is a string with  áccents.");`

Answer (score 1):

Another possible solution (fixed/adapted from Cortright's answer) is to enumerate the Unicode pairs.

```
const string input = "This is a stríng with áccents .";
byte[] array = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(input);

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i += 2)
{
    if (((array[i]) | (array[i + 1] << 8)) > 128)
    {
        Console.WriteLine((array[i] | (array[i + 1] << 8)) + " at index " + (i / 2) + " is not within the ASCII range");
    }
}
```

This prints a list of all the numerical values that are outside the range of allowed ASCII values. (I am taking the original definition of ASCII as 0-127.)

Personally, I recommend David Arno's solution. I only post this as a potential alternative. (It **could** be faster, if you benchmark it. Just as well, it **could** also be more manageable.)

Update: I did just test it, and it seems it still properly recognizes characters within the higher range (U+10000 - U+10FFFF) as **not** being allowed. This is, in fact, due to the surrogate pairs being outside the ASCII range as well. The only issue is that it recognizes them as **two** character pairs, not one.

Output:

```
237 at index 13 is not within the ASCII range
225 at index 22 is not within the ASCII range
55378 at index 30 is not within the ASCII range
57186 at index 31 is not within the ASCII range
```